# How to re waterproof cloth diapers?

Tags: cloth-diaper

We have a number of Cloth Diapers ([Mama Koala if it matters](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LVWQY6K)) that have worked great, but recently, some of them are beginning to leak through the fabric.

How can I safely (to my toddler) re apply waterproofing to them?

Comment: I have also reached out to Mama Koala customer service about this and will update if they respond.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can; it's a problem with all-in-one washable nappies.

We used a system with a separate water-proof cover and an absorbent towel inner. The outers needed replacing after a few months, the inners lasted years.

Comment: This model is essentially what you describe. A tough outer (waterproof) layer, with a pocket for absorbent inner layer(s).

Comment: In which case, I imagine they expect you to just buy a new outer when it leaks. Hopefully you're about due to move up a size anyway. If they've failed much faster than that, you might be able to send them back as faulty.

Comment: They're not "sized" like that, they're adjustable. So, they should (in theory) fit for as long as the child needs them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can still buy baby laundry powder that is actually **soap**, it will make your covers more waterproof. When we used cloth diapers we washed clothes and covers in Baby Snow, which is chemically soap. It makes things feel soft (because of the waxy fatty soap I guess) and much less absorbent. We washed the diapers in **detergent**, which kept them absorbent. (And we had arguments with people who "helped" us by doing a load of laundry and insisting that we were wrong and the diapers had to be washed in the Baby Snow, and then dealt with non absorbent diapers until a few washes had gone by.)

I see baby detergent with Snow in the name these days, but it's liquid detergent. It may take some sleuthing to find actual soap.